# How to hide/disable default only error message "Your request failed to complete." liferay 7

Tags: liferay-7

I want to hide one of the error message appearing

> Your request failed to complete.

from all the portlets when user enters wrong credentials. Image attached for reference. Only red marked message i want to remove.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Please consider providing a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways but the most stupid and simple on is to use CSS to hide the unwanted message.

```
#portlet_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet .lfr-alert-
   wrapper:first-of-type{
   display:none !important;
}
```

Alternatively, you would need to modify the login portlet with a JSP fragment.